# Android Fetch Contacts into the Application

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I am trying to show a list of Contacts from the users phone in a List view inside the application. I am able to fetch the contacts but some of the Contacts will have mutiple cellphone numbers so i want to show that person that many number of times.

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    String name, number = "";
    String id;
    c.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
        name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
            Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                    null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            }
        }
        Log.i("name ", name + " ");
        Log.i("number ", number + " ");
        c.moveToNext();
```

Want to Display a user as many times as the number of numbers he has. Will i be even able to short list it based of only cellphone numbers which is 10 digit long ?

```
Example

Name: John Doe 
Number 1: xxxxxxxxx
Number 2: xxxxxxxxx

Name: Sarah 
Number 1: xxxxxxxxx
```

This should return be three List Items as Follows

```
John Doe  xxxxxxxxx
John Doe  xxxxxxxxx
Sarah     xxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @mach Want to Display a user as many times as the number of numbers he has. Will i be even able to short list it based of only cellphone numbers which is 10 digit long ?

Comment: Do you not want to use a ExpandableListView and have the numbers as sub-elements?

Comment: no i want them as indiviual list item so that it can be selected by the user. i want to fetch the Name and Phone number basically.

Comment: What about creating VO of the contact. like {name, number} and if you found multtipple PhoneNumber create a separate VO  and add to a list and use this list as the DataProvider For your Adpater

Comment: I am not clear what you want here. You want to show all the contacts that has phone numbers. And if a contact has several phone numbers then sort the by phone numbers? am I right?

Comment: @HoanNguyen i have added an example.

Comment: @RajeshCP what is a VO ?

Comment: ValueObject :O like class having some properties and method to access those properties

Comment: You want to show the bottom list above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try something like this

```
List<PhoneItem> phoneNoList = new ArrayList<PhoneItem();
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
String name, number = "";
String id;
c.moveToFirst();
for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
    name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

    if (Integer.parseInt(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
        Cursor pCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                null);
        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
            phoneNoList.add(new PhoneItem(name, pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))));
        }
    }
    c.moveToNext();


}

for (PhoneItem row : phoneNoList) {
    Log.i("name", row.name);
    Log.i("number", row.number+"");
}

[...]

private class PhoneItem {
   String name;
   String phone;

   public PhoneItem(String name, String phone) {
       this.name = name;
       this.phone = phone;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will fetch all contacts with phone numbers. There maybe duplicate because the same contact may belong to different group. You have to loop though and eliminate the duplicate.

```
String[] projection = new String[]{ ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,};
String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=?" ;  
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] {"1"};                            
Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                                    projection, 
                                    selection, 
                                    selectionArgs, 
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
                                    + ", " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
```